# How to target the nth-of-type of an element using styled-components

Tags: css, css-selectors, styled-components

I have this `styled-component`. I would like to target the 2nd `<Badge />` via css and `styled-components` however I cannot get it to work.  I have tried multiple ways, but still I'm stuck.

```
//... maps through data and produces 2 cards with their title, price and discount (Badge)

        <CardContainerText>
          <CardTitle>{t(`${product.productName}`)}</CardTitle>{" "}
          <CardPrice>{t(`${totalPrice}€ / an`)}</CardPrice>
          {rate.amount > 0 && <Badge>Discount {rate.amount}% </Badge> }          </CardContainerText>
      </CardHeading>
```

This will produce the following `html`.

```
<div> CARD 1
  <h1>card title</h1>
  <p>card price</p>
  <span>card badge</span>
</div>
<div> CARD 2
  <h1>card title 2</h1>
  <p>card price 2</p>
  <span>card badge 2</span>
</div>
```

I will like to target card badge 2  with style-components so I can style it properly.

My `<Badge />` css looks like this:

```
export const Badge = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -233px;
  right: 61px;
  padding: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);

  @media (min-width: 740px) {
    top: -68px;
    right: 150px;
    padding: 8px;

  [ASK]: Here I want that the second badge has a different top position. But this does not work.
    &:nth-of-type(2n) {
      top: -95px;
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: I can't see _2nd `<Badge />`_? do you mean the `<Badge />` inside the 2nd `<CardContainerText>`?

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj yes the second `<Badge />` inside the second `<CardContainerText />` not seeing here,  but once I loop through it I get *2* of these `<CardContainerText> <Badge /> </CardContainerText>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at this a bit different: you want the `Badge` in the 2nd `CardContainerText` to have different styling

```js
export const Badge = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -233px;
  right: 61px;
  padding: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);

  @media (min-width: 740px) {
    top: -68px;
    right: 150px;
    padding: 8px;
  }
`;

const CardContainerText = styled.div`
  &:nth-of-type(2n) { /* this matches all even (2nd) CardContainerText */
    @media (min-width: 740px) {
      ${Badge} {  /* this matches the Badge in the 2nd container for yor media query */
        top: -95px;
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This uses `styled-components` ability to [refer other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a class for the badge.
Like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```